# Scipy.signal find_peaks array dimension error

Tags: python, scipy

I'm looking through several hundred data files looking for peaks in a signal. I have the data in a numpy array and am trying to use the `find_peaks` method from scipy. However no matter what I try I get:

> ValueError: `x` must have exactly one dimension

Here is the code:

```
#Load electron signal data from file
data = np.loadtxt("C3tsss00001.txt", delimiter=" ", skiprows=5, dtype=float)

time, volts = np.hsplit(data, 2)

voltssmth = savgol_filter(volts, 5, 2, mode='nearest')

print(volts)
print(voltssmth)

#Invert negative detected signals into positive ones
volts = volts * -1
voltssmth = voltssmth * -1


#find peak due to detected electrons
peaks, _ =find_peaks(volts, height = .005)
```

This is the complete error Traceback
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-950424021ed6>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('//phypcs/smith.10851$/Roaming Profile/Desktop/03.22.19    /MCPtest.py')

  File "C:\Users\smith.10851\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\smith.10851\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "//phypcs/smith.10851$/Roaming Profile/Desktop/03.22.19/MCPtest.py", line 32, in <module>
peaks, _ =find_peaks(volts, height = .005)

File "C:\Users\smith.10851\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\_peak_finding.py", line 875, in find_peaks
raise ValueError('`x` must have exactly one dimension')
```

ValueError: `x` must have exactly one dimension

And here is a small portion of the data giving the issue:

```
LECROYWP725Zi 0 Waveform
Segments 1 SegmentSize 10002
Segment TrigTime TimeSinceSegment1
#1 22-Mar-2019 18:12:19 0                 
Time Ampl
-5.4942647e-011 0.000339844
4.5057353e-011 0.000337891
1.4505735e-010 0.000330078
2.4505735e-010 0.000310547
3.4505735e-010 0.000289062
4.4505735e-010 0.000285156
5.4505735e-010 0.000210938
6.4505735e-010 0.000166016
7.4505735e-010 0.000115234
8.4505735e-010 0.000113281
9.4505735e-010 0.000111328
1.0450574e-009 9.57031e-005
1.1450574e-009 6.83594e-005
1.2450574e-009 3.90625e-005
1.3450574e-009 4.49219e-005
1.4450574e-009 3.125e-005
1.5450574e-009 -2.34375e-005
1.6450574e-009 -5.66406e-005
1.7450574e-009 -0.000101563
1.8450574e-009 -0.000103516
1.9450574e-009 -9.375e-005
2.0450574e-009 -0.000111328
2.1450574e-009 -8.98437e-005
2.2450574e-009 -0.000121094
2.3450574e-009 -0.000130859
2.4450574e-009 -0.000119141
2.5450574e-009 -0.000136719
2.6450574e-009 -0.000138672
```

Comment: What is `volts.shape`?  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, when you report a Python error message, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Is this better? new to asking questions here and asking for help with my code in general. Any feedback to make the question clearer and easier to respond to is greatly appreciated. I was orginally using volts.shape (numpy.ndarray.shape) to verify that the numpy array I am feeding the find_peaks method was the correct dimension.

Comment: Thanks.  Now modify the code to print `volts.shape` before calling `find_peaks`, and show the output so we can see what it is.  `find_peaks` expects a *one-dimensional* array, so the shape should be something like `(N,)` (for some integer `N`).  I think you'll see when you print it that it is `(N, 1)`, which means your `volts` array is a two-dimensional array.  That is what `hsplit` returns.